# Setup mySQL in a chroot in Debian Wheezy

Tags: mysql-5.5, security, configuration, debian

Sounds like a simple question, but the documentation is rare about what mySQL needs to run inside a chroot.

I think I'm almost there, but I'm running into a permission problem that I can't solve, and `mysql-server` won't start.

`# mysqld
[ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
[Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/***.lower-test
[Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/***.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2)
[ERROR] Aborting
[Note]`

I installed the `mysql-server` package from dotdeb on a clean Debian Wheezy.

It works fine when not chrooted.

I've obviously read the -*very concise*- [official doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_chroot) about the `chroot` option.

I've read many howtos and I ended up following [this one (in French)](http://www.cgsecurity.org/Articles/mysql.html)

**What I've done**

- stopped mysql server
- created a directory structure for the chroot : `/var/chroot/mysql`

  `|____var
  | |____lib
  | | |____mysql
  | | | |____performance_schema
  | | | |____mysql
  | |____run
  | | |____mysqld
  | |____log
  |____usr
  | |____share
  | | |____zoneinfo
  (...)
  | | |____mysql
  (...)
  | |____lib
  | | |____x86_64-linux-gnu
  |____lib
  | |____x86_64-linux-gnu
  |____lib64
  |____tmp
  |____etc`
- the whole tree belongs to `mysql:mysql` and with `rw` on files and `rwx` on dirs
- `tmp` has 1777 perms
- moved `/var/lib/mysql` to `/var/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql` and made a symbolic link back from `/var/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql` to `/var/lib/mysql`
- same with `/var/run/mysqld`
- copied `/usr/share/mysql` to `/var/chroot/mysql/usr/share/mysql`
- copied all libs returned by `ldd /usr/sbin/mysqld` under `/var/chroot/mysql/path_to_lib`
  changed the owner to `mysql:mysql` but kept the permissions from the main filesystem
- copied `/etc/localtime` and `/usr/share/zoneinfo` to my chroot
- copied `/etc/passwd` to my chroot, and kept only the line for `mysql` user
- edited `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

`[client]
port       = 3306
socket     = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`


`[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0`


`[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
skip-show-database
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
 #max_connections        = 100
 #max_user_connections   = 50
 #table_cache            = 64
 #thread_concurrency     = 10
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
 # Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/slow.log
long_query_time = 2
 #log-queries-not-using-indexes
 #server-id     = 1
 #log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
 #binlog_do_db      = include_database_name
 #binlog_ignore_db  = include_database_name
chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
 # ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
 # ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
 # ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem`


`[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M`


`[mysql]
 #no-auto-rehash    # faster start of mysql but no tab completion`


`[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M`


`!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/`

*(I removed irrelevent comments)*

I had to change some options names as the file used obsolete forms (like `key_buffer` instead of `key_buffer_size`)

Anyway, the important part is :

`datadir=/var/lib/mysql
chroot=/var/lib/mysql`

`datadir` is supposed to be relative to `chroot` so it should point to `/var/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql` (where my dbs are actually stored).
Even though it were an absolute path to `/var/lib/mysql`, this is a symlink to `/var/chroot/mysql/var/lib/mysql`, so it shouldn't be a problem.

**What I get**

Now, whether I run `service mysql start` or `mysqld` (as root, of course), I get the same message, either on screen or in `/var/log/syslog`:

`[ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
[Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/***.lower-test
[Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/***.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2)
[ERROR] Aborting
[Note]`

*(I've also made a symlink on `/var/chroot/mysql/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys` to `french/errmsg.sys`)*

It looks like `mysql-server` is not looking at the right place.

But why, and what can I do to make it work ?

Comment: chroot should be **/var/chroot/mysql** (as often, the answer was in the question)

Comment: Don't edit the question (with **"solved"**), if it has been solved. You can mark the answer (even your answer) with the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, as often, the answer was in the question.

Must've been pretty tired, because as I said :

> Anyway, the important part is : 
>   
>   `datadir=/var/lib/mysql
>   chroot=/var/lib/mysql`

But, if I wanna be consistent with myself, `chroot` must be `/var/chroot/mysql`.

So the correct setting is :

`datadir=/var/lib/mysql
chroot=/var/chroot/mysql`

And indeed it works !

Hope this can be useful to somebody trying to run mysql in chroot.